# Having trouble with mongoDB projection with condition

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Suppose I have the following data in another collection called 'Collection1'

```
userID: "1"
container:[
    {"item" : "false", "price" : NumberDecimal("80"), "sizes" : "S", "arrayIndex" : NumberLong(0) }
    {"item" : "false", "price" : NumberDecimal("80"), "sizes" : "M", "arrayIndex" : NumberLong(1) }
    {"item" : "true", "price" : NumberDecimal("80"), "sizes" : "L", "arrayIndex" : NumberLong(2) }
]
```

I join 'Collection1' to my main query as follows (There are many suff being done prior to the joint and I want to simplify this)

```
    {$lookup:{
        from:'Collection1',
  localField:'result',
foreignField:'userID',
          as:'photos'
    }},

    {$unwind:{
        path:'$photos',
        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays:true
    }},
```

Up until now, everything is good until I do a project.

```
{$project:
   {'photo':
   {$cond:{
      if:{$eq:['$photos.container.item',false]},
      then:'$photos.container.price',
      else:null
       }
    }
 }},
```

Projecting any element without the condition works. However, I am also doing a projection with another condition and there is no problem there.

The expected output would be

```
[
 {
   otherElement:....
   photos:{
     price:80
   }
 }
]
```

Could anyone tell me why this doesn't work. Again, I am sorry I had to simplify this somehow. If this is not clear, I can try to make it more understandable.

Comment: Its working https://mongoplayground.net/p/1_eR39u793_

Comment: @varman Alright, I changed the script and I believe it should not work this time because it's in an Array? Could you please confirm? Thank you for looking at this btw.

Comment: When you post a queation, please double check that you included everything that others understand. And please post some sample data (both collections)

Comment: @PatrickAdjei What is your expected result? can you add in your question.

Comment: @verman please specify what you need. I would be happy to provide it. The data provided at the very start of the question is not enough? I tried to keep it brief.

Comment: @turivishal I added the output I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Your container field is an array so doing this $`eq:['$photos.container.item',false]` will not work directly, you need to unwind `container` first to convert it to an object like below.

```
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$photos.container",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
```

Here is the working example [MongoDB Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/X0LbM-p1Z9X)

Comment: It doesn't unwind the container. I had already tried this and I just confirmed once more.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, is should not be unwinding the array. Instead I should project and filter with a condition.

```
{$project:
   {'photos':
      {$filter:
         {
         input:'$photos.container',
         as:'photo',
         cond:{
             $eq:['$$photo.profilePic',true]
              }
         }
    }
}}
```

Thank you guys so much for looking at this. I appreciate it!